# C++ exclude part of loop operator on last loop

Tags: c++, loops, iteration, cout

I am trying to figure out how to include a cout with a for loop that leaves off part of the cout on the last iteration. I want to have a multiplication sign (*) after each number (nFact) EXCEPT the last number in the loop.

Current output: 5*4*3*2*1*
Ideal output: 5*4*3*2*1

'''

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
nFact = nFact*(n-i);
cout << (n - i)<<"*";
}
```

'''

Comment: Simple -- Figure out whether to print the multiplication sign *before* the number, not after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
nFact = nFact*(n-i);
if(i!=n-1)
cout << (n - i)<<"*";
else  cout << (n - i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might do:

```
const char* sep = "";
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    nFact *= n - i;
    std::cout << sep << n - i;
    sep = "*";
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/UAKDAY)